# jQuery: Transform JSON-Object to HTML-List improvements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have written a function which transforms a multidimensional json-object to an html list:
http://jsfiddle.net/KcvG6/

1. Why does the function render the lists double?
   Update: http://jsfiddle.net/KcvG6/2/
2. Are there any improvements about the logic to do?
3. The original JSON-object generates urls in the url attribute.
   These urls are generated with a given slug. If the given slug is not yet available (the user hasn't selected anything or what else the link should not be rendered:

   ```
   'image': {
       'index': {
           'name': 'Show all images',
           'url': Routing.generate('AcmeImageBundle_Image_index')
       },
       'new': {
           'name': 'Add new image',
           'url': Routing.generate('AcmeImageBundle_Image_new')
       },
       'edit': {
           'name': 'Edit selected image',
           'url': Routing.generate('AcmeImageBundle_Image_edit', { 'slug': imageSlug })
       },
       'delete': {
           'name': 'Delete selected image',
           'url': Routing.generate('AcmeImageBundle_Image_delete', { 'slug': imageSlug })
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens twice because of the call to .children(). You are replacing each child element with the list. Instead, select the first child and replace it.

```
$(container).children().first().replaceWith(renderList(objectCollection));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KcvG6/1/

If you need to remove the `<p>` element, do that separately.

Comment: Hi, cant I remove all childrens. Something like div > or div *?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/VF2sm/

Assuming you just want to replace the `ul` in your document, calling `.children` is not enough. You need to use `.find`, otherwise it will replace ALL children, of which you currently have 2

```
$(container).find('ul').replaceWith(renderList(objectCollection));
```

Or you could easily wipe out the entire contents and repace it with your list like this:

```
$(container).html(renderList(objectCollection));
```

As far the quality of your `renderList()` function, I think its just fine.

Comment: Hi look at my update in the start post. Any suggestions about point 2 and 3?

Comment: Well on point 1/2. `.html()` is much better and simpler than: `.children().remove()` then `.append` in your fiddle update. As for point 3. I don't understand, no user interaction is in your script, so I don't know what you mean by 'the user hasn't selected anything' or the link is unavailable.

Comment: Hi, indeed point 3 is hard to explain. So imagine I have two entities. Each entity can be changed by three actions (new, edit, delete). The edit and delete actions require a special url (with parameter). If I now want to manage another entity or the parameter for the edit and delete actions are missing and so they are useless and shouldn't get rendered

Comment: Can you provide a greater code sample. So far I would consider 3 unanswerable.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/KcvG6/5/ (Routing.generate starts an ajax request generating the whole url from the framework routing config) It now works from the functional aspect more or less (the hiding of unvalid url is missing) but it is far away from smart